# facebook post screen not dismis automatically

Tags: swift

i am trying to post images on facebook from my app but SharePost screen is not automatically dismis after post successfully uploded
Here is my code:

```
let content:FBSDKSharePhotoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
content.photos = [self.sharePhoto]
let shareDialog: FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
shareDialog.shareContent = content
shareDialog.delegate = self
shareDialog.fromViewController = self
shareDialog.show()
```

FBSdk SharingDelegate Methods:

```
func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: 
    [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
    print(results)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
    print(error)
}

func sharerDidCancel(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!) {
    print("Cancel")
}
```